# unexpected parenthesis in batch file

Tags: windows, cmd

i have batch code that <del>will</del> should allow me to type "mindustry" (that is the file name) it the will prompt me for what version, it stops working after i type "v3" without quotation marks

```
    @echo off
    for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10) do echo.
    echo here are what versions of Mindustry i have:
    echo -  v3 (version 3)
    echo -  b4 (version 4 beta)
    set /p version = "what version will you play >>> "

    @echo on

    if /I %version%=="v3" (
        cd mindustrypc/v3 ::go to minustry's location
        mindustry ::open mindustry.exe it is the game i have multiple versions of and why i have the launcher code
        exit
    )
```

i get this when i run it:

```
C:\Users\■■■■■>mindustry










here are what versions of mindustry i have:
-  v3 (version 3)
-  b4 (version 4 beta)
what version will you play >>> v3
( was unexpected at this time.
C:\Users\■■■■■>if /I =="v3" (
C:\Users\■■■■■>
```

note that i typed v3, it did not do that automatically. i also noticed that it does not recognise my variable

does anybody know what is up with my code? i will be adding 1 more if statement to check if if i input "b4".

Comment: Unless you enter `"v3"` with double quotes your if will never be true. Your `set /p` also assigns the variable `%version %` with a trailing space, in a batch set don't put spaces arounf the equal sign. Checking input for validity is much easier with `choice.exe`

Comment: what is choice.exe

Comment: [choice.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html)